# Bank nifty option price using Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping. I intend to load current option price for particular strike price from nse website. Following are the codes I have written:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url ='https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=BANKNIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&strike=20200.00&type=CE&expiry=23APR2020'
head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}

page = requests.get(url,headers=head)
page_content = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content,'html.parser')
tabl = soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "stock"})
for t in tabl:
    rows = t.find_all("li")
temp_dir= {}
for row in rows:
    if len(row.get_text(separator='|').split("|")[0:2])>0:
        temp_dir[row.get_text(separator='|').split("|")[0]]=row.get_text(separator='|').split("|")[-1]
```

However the output of temp_dir:

```
{'--': '\n',
 'Prev. Close': '--',
 'Open': '--',
 'High': '--',
 'Low': '--',
 'Close': '--'}
```

I am not able to see the price. Please help

Comment: If you print(tabl), you will see why you have your issue. The values in the requested page are --

Comment: Yes. I do have noticed it. But where am I wrong? which link should have been linked?

Comment: I am not sure why. Typically the reason is headers, but you seem to have those. Whether they are the correct ones or not I am not sure. You can try this https://github.com/swapniljariwala/nsepy

Comment: I have used NSEpy but it gives historical data. I need live data.